# how to make rxjs observable repeat and retryWhen run together (same index)?

Tags: javascript, angular, rxjs, observable

**SHORT VERSION**

how can I make the rxjs `observable.pipe(repeat(10), retryWhen())` run together? I want my angular http.get to run 10 times, no matter if it fails or succeeds

**LONG VERSION**

so I have an angular 5 app that sends a request to a server to process many distinct services at the same time, and as each one of them complete, a json is filled until all services complete.

as soon as my app requests that, it starts http.getting the response json, that might (and probably) wont be complete the first few times it requests. Knowing that, I want the http.get observable to do the following:

- Try getting the response a max number of times (10 times, for example)
- If the json returns complete before that, end the observable
- The server returns an error when no services finished yet, but as soon as the first service finishes, a json is returned successfully, so I want retry(10) and repeat(10) rxjs functions to run together (with the same index, so if it fails 2 times, the repeat should be in the 3rd try too)

this is what I have so far:

```
http.get(route).pipe(
    retryWhen(myRetry()), //myRetry() has no implementation yet
    repeat(10),
    takeWhile(json => !json.finished)
).subscribe(...);
```

but I believe this retries 10 times first, then repeats 10 times, which isnt what I want. Any suggestions on better structuring/changing the whole thing is welcome

Answer (score 0):

Just use `repeat` and ignore errors

```
http.get(route).pipe(
    catchError(() => EMPTY)
    repeat(10),
    takeWhile(json => !json.finished)
).subscribe(...);
```

Comment: how do I identify when the http.get returns an error then?

Comment: in `catchError` you handle the error, but return `EMPTY` observable which will ignore the error and `repeat` will resubscribe the observable as normal.

Comment: I actually need to catch the error, so I cant return empty, but if it happens everytime the repeat returns an error, then I guess thats what I was looking for. Thanks